# Не могу задать linear-gradient родителю

Tags: html, css, css3

Пол дня бьюсь.. Не могу задать `linear-gradient` родителю, тогда как у дочерних элементов (`main-block__container`) он работает. `z-index` не работает для `main-block`

html

```css
.wrapper {
  min-height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

._container {
  max-width: 107rem;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
._container__narrow {
  max-width: 80rem;
  box-sizing: content-box;
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.page {
  flex: 1 1 auto;
}
._bgimg {
  position: relative;
}

._bgimg img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  object-fit: cover;
}

.main-block {
  position: relative;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #242633 11.98%, rgba(45, 52, 60, 0.38) 51.04%, #242B33 92.19%);
}

.main-block__container {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
  padding: 29.6rem 0 7.4rem;
}
        
.main-block__img {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
.main-block__title {
  font-size: 4.8rem;
  line-height: 133.3333333333%;
  margin: 0 0 10rem;
}

.main-block__icon {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-bottom: 20rem;
}

.main-block__contacts {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -ms-flex-pack: distribute;
  justify-content: space-around;
}

.main-block__contact {
  font-size: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 116.6666666667%;
  padding: 0 0 0 3rem;
}

.main-block__contact:first-child {
  background: url("../img/icons/place.svg") left center no-repeat;
}

.main-block__contact:last-child {
  background: url("../img/icons/tel.svg") left center no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<section class="main-block">
    <div class="main-block__container _container__narrow">
        <h1 class="main-block__title title">blablablalblabla</h1>
        <img src="img/icons/mouse.svg" alt="scroll" class="main-block__icon">
        <ul class="main-block__contacts">
            <li class="main-block__contact"><a href="#map" class="main-block__link">addr</a></li>
            <li class="main-block__contact"><a href="tel:" class="main-block__link">1 (123) 123-45-67</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="main-block__img _bgimg">
        <img src="img/main-background.jpg" alt="bgbgbf">
    </div>

</section>
```

Comment: Нашел на просторах как наложить градиент псевдо элементом after, но все равно оч интересно, почему не срабатывает по родителю.

Comment: запустил сниппет, градиент прорисовывается. Уточните вопрос. Нажмите в вашем примере кнопку "выполнить код"

Comment: Его не видно под изображением, которое является фоном. Посмотрите код пожалуйста. И никак его не вывести по оси z

Comment: Снипет не воспроизводит проблему. Почитайте пожалуйста  [mre]. Не могу понять какой результат вы хотите получить

Comment: Я задаю задний фон тегом img <div class="main-block__img _bgimg">
        <img src="img/main-background.jpg" alt="bgbgbf">
    </div>, а градиент задаю родительскому блоку <section class="main-block">. Проблема в том, что градиент всегда под img

Comment: Так вы хотите спрятать картинку за градиентом? Не ставьте картинку и градиент будет видим. Вы в сниппетах можете использовать картинки с сайтов генераторов случайных картинок

Comment: Сделал псевдо элементом after. но... есть ли способ задать градиент родителю, не трогая картинку?

Comment: Я так и не понял, вы хотите чтоб картинка поверх градиента была или градиент поверх картинки (если да то картинки же не будет видно). Если вы ставите градиент над картинкой то зачем картинка?

Comment: Уважаемый, я пытаюсь задать градиент для картинки через родительский класс. Вопрос в том, почему картинка всегда поверх градиента и как, соответственно, сделать так, чтобы градиент был поверх. И если вам действительно интересно, градиент полупрозрачный, картинку видно, но это абсолютно не касается темы вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Все дело в [контексте наложения](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Positioning/Understanding_z_index/The_stacking_context), если вы родить задаёте z-index то дочерние элементы не опустятся ниже его

По поводу комментария:

> И если вам действительно интересно, градиент полупрозрачный, картинку видно, но это абсолютно не касается темы вопроса.

Как раз касается это вопроса, если честно, нет времени разбираться в html структуре и понять что автор хотел этим получить, если вы упрощаете до **минимального воспроизводимого примера**, то отвечающему достаточно нажать кнопку запустить в сниппете

Такой результат вы ожидали?:

```css
.container {
  width: 400px;
  height: 200px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(180deg, #242633 11.98%, rgba(45, 52, 60, 0.38) 51.04%, #242B33 92.19%)
}


.image-wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
}

.image {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="image-wrapper">
    <img src="https://www.fillmurray.com/640/360" class="image" />
  </div>
</div>
```